# Why am I getting this Maven error?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I've been trying to fix this problem for a good part of an hour now, and I haven't gotten anywhere.

When I attempt to compile my project using Maven, I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project GankALane: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single for parameter archive: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration for 'descriptorRefs'

I'm compiling by using the command: 
`mvn clean compile assembly:single`

and here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>GankALane</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>beam-releases</id>
            <url>https://maven.beam.pro/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>beam-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://maven.beam.pro/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pro.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pro.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>interactive</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.me.GankALane.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks for looking, and hopefully I can find a solution!

Comment: Though still in the [v3.3.9 Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) the [maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-assembly-plugin%22) is more than 6 years old. I don't know if this solves your problem but I'd use the latest [v2.6](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|maven-assembly-plugin).

Comment: Just tried that, no difference

Comment: You bound the `single` goal of the `maven-assembly-plugin` to the `package` phase. Why do you perform `mvn clean compile assembly:single` instead of [`mvn clean package`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html#Execution:_Building_an_Assembly) then?

Comment: I put the wrong command on the question, let me fix that, my bad @GeroldBroser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POM is wrong:

```
<configuration>
    <archive>
        ...  
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </archive>
</configuration>
```

The message gives the hint:

> parameter archive: Cannot find setter, adder nor field ... for 'descriptorRefs'

See  [Apache Maven Assembly Plugin > Usage](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html):

```
<configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
```

which also links to [Apache Maven Archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) at the beginning: no `<archive>/<descriptorRefs>` there.